# Convert String to datetime in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How will I convert date in the format `Sat Mar 29 00:00:00 EST 1975` to `datetime` in TSQL?

I get the date in this format from an old table which defined the date of birth column as `NVARCHAR` and stores the data as `Mon Jun dd hh:mm:ss GMT yyyy` format. I need to read another table which has the dob in `datetime` using this value.

So basically I want to convert, say `Sat Mar 29 00:00:00 EST 1975` to `1975-03-29 00:00:00.000`

Is there a way in T-SQL to do this conversion? I tried the `CONVERT` function, but I am unable to locate the correct 'style' to use.

Comment: [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp)

Comment: Once you figure out how to convert it I would highly recommend you change the datatype to datetime. Storing your data in the proper datatype makes things so much easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks @huMptyduMpty for the link. That is very comprehensive.

Comment: @SeanLange, yes I know. But that is the problem with legacy systems we have to deal with on a daily basis. The cost to improve is much more than the cost to keep running the ineffective existing piece of crap (pardon my language) :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining the data format, it appears to be a fixed length string.

The first portion is the day of week, which can be discarded as it isn't needed for parsing.  Next you have the month and day information, which we need.  After that is the time, which can be retained or discarded depending on whether you want a date or datetime as output.

Since you are looking for a date of birth, the time zone information can most likely be safely discarded.

Finally, there is the year.

If we eliminate the day of week and the time zone, sql server will parse the rest of the string with no problem.

I recommend `cast(substring(@difficultTime,5,7) + substring(@difficultTime,25,4) as date)`, where @difficulteTime is the column name you are converting.

If you wanted to retain the time information, the following format will work `cast(substring(@difficultTime,5,16) + substring(@difficultTime,25,4) as datetime)`

This assumes that your strings will be of a fixed length.  The first conversion shown eliminates the day of week, the time, and the time zone from the string, leaving a parseable date.

The second conversion eliminates the day of week and the time zone, leaving a parseable datetime.